# Customize Sherlock Actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Please help me this question. 
I am trying to customize the Action Bar sherlock. Please see my image :
[Image](http://imageshack.us/a/img26/2416/indicatorl.png)(Sorry because I don't have enough reputation to upload image)

My question :

1. How can I change the icon on this image(in red part).
2. Or do you know what does it name?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are Pros and Cons in action bar sherlock

Comment: See my answer, if it will do any good. However, I wouldn't suggest you to change the overflow icon. It's a pattern that Android users are getting used to and so they know what the "three dots" do. If you change it, users could get confused.

Comment: yes. I see. But I did it because UI design from customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting this to your theme (values/themes.xml):

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MyOverflow</item>
</style>
```

and this to theme for v11 (values-v11/themes.xml)

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MyOverflow</item>
</style>
```

and finally to values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="Widget.MyOverflow" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/some_other_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Take a look on files values/abs_*themes.xml and values/abs*_styles.xml in ActionBarSherlock project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't change this icon unless you modify ActionBarSherlock. That's the action overflow menu.

From the documentation:

"By default, the system places all items in the action overflow, which the user can reveal with the action overflow icon on the right side of the action bar (or by pressing the device Menu button, if available). To enable quick access to important actions, you can promote a few items to appear in the action bar by adding android:showAsAction="ifRoom" to the corresponding  elements"

Comment: Thanks João Melo. It is a bad news for me, If we can't change this icon :(

Comment: Why do you need to change the icon of the action overflow menu? Just esthetics?

Comment: I need to change it because the app design from customer. Please see cermak.cz comment. It work for me :)

Comment: Haven't thought of overriding android:src from abs styles! Great solution!